# What commands can git pull be separated to?

Tags: git

When pulling, i noticed `git fetch` behavior also occurs.

I assume a pull is actually

`pull = fetch + x`

I was wondering if this is the case, and if so, what is `x`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the `git pull` documentation

> Incorporates changes from a remote repository into the current branch. In its default mode, git pull is shorthand for git
>          fetch followed by git merge FETCH_HEAD.

So the missing `x` is a `merge`, for the default behavior.

Answer (score 0):

What `git pull` does is `git fetch` followed by a `git merge`.

More precisely, `git pull` runs `git fetch` with the given parameters and calls `git merge` to merge the retrieved branch heads into the current branch

Answer (score 0):

fetch really only downloads new data from a remote repository - but it doesn't integrate any of this new data into your working files.

pull, in contrast, is used with a different goal in mind: to update your current HEAD branch with the latest changes from the remote server.